# Get object's class name in ES5/ES5.1

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-compatiblity

In [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) there is `.constructor.name` which can be used on any object to get its class name.

Is there something in [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009) that can do that?

(Note: Before commenters mention to upgrade the browser, etc., this question is about development for [Fitbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitbit#Products), which uses [JerryScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JerryScript), a lightweight ES5.1-based engine)

TLDR of code that does not work:

```js
class something {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name);
  }
}

new something();
```

It should normally output `something`, I guess, but it just says `undefined`.

Comment: it's the same `.constructor.name`

Comment: How about `.constructor.toString()` ? It should be `function <NAME>(...) {..}` so you should be able to extract it with some regular expression.

Comment: Are you saying you tried `.constructor.name` in ES5-1 and you got an error or something unexpected? Can you clarify?

Comment: basically I get undefined.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli In 5.1 [`.toString()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2) is implementation-dependent, so...

Answer (score 2):

[ES5.1 function objects](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.3) did not have a `.name` property. This was a [widely-supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#browser_compatibility) but non-standard extension that only got [added to the spec with ES6](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name).

CoreJs has [a polyfill for it](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.function.name.js) which relies on `Function.prototype.toString()`, which is supported in the latest JerryScript but may have to be enabled with the `JERRY_FUNCTION_TO_STRING` build option.

Answer (score 1):

[Section 13.2](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-13.2) of the ECMAScript 5.1 specification explains how all functions have a `prototype` property which itself has a `constructor` property.

> A `prototype` property is automatically created for every function, to allow for the possibility that the function will be used as a constructor.

> 16. Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 17. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments `"constructor"`, Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: *F*, { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.

So any object created with `new someFunction` should, by default, inherit the `constructor` property whose value is the `someFunction` function. The specification also specifies the `constructor` property of builtin object prototypes.

**However, it does not mention the existence of a `name` property on constructors or functions.** So if you want to specifically get the name of the constructor as a string, you would have to extract it from the representation returned by `.toString()` which is defined as such:

> An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*. Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.

Alternatively, you can use [`Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) to produce a string which exposes the internal [[Class]] of a value, which is slightly different notion than the constructor property. Again, you'll have to extract the [[Class]] from the string yourself. Sadly, for custom functions, that just returns `[object Object]`, so probably not what you're looking for.

> 1. If the **this** value is **undefined**, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the **this** value is **null**, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let *O* be the result of calling ToObject passing the **this** value as the argument.
> 4. Let *class* be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *O*.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, *class*, and `"]"`.

Comment: The *[[Class]]* internal property will only be `Object` (or `Function`, `RegExp` or `Array`), but not the name of a user-defined constructor function

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I just updated my post to mention that directly. Perhaps I was too eager to be exhaustive and mentioning I could have left out the part about [[Class]] entirely 